# How can I generate qr code and not save the qr code image to the folder?

Tags: php, image, qr-code

I am using http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ to generate qr code. But here have a problem, is when I generate qr code, but the qr code will automatically save in `$tempDir = "qrcodes/";`, so I want to know how can I just generate the qr code, but no any image will save in the folder?

**This is my code:**

```
<?php 
            include 'phpqrcode.php';
            include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');

            // how to save PNG codes to server
            $uuid = md5(uniqid());
            $uuidsha1 = sha1($uuid); 

            $codeContents = $uuidsha1;
            $tempDir = "qrcodes/";
            // we need to generate filename somehow, 
            // with md5 or with database ID used to obtains $codeContents...
            $fileName = ''.md5($codeContents).'.png';

            $pngAbsoluteFilePath = $tempDir.$fileName;
            $urlRelativeFilePath = $tempDir.$fileName;

            // generating
            QRcode::png($codeContents, $pngAbsoluteFilePath, QR_ECLEVEL_H, 8, 1, false);

            // displaying
            echo '<img src="'.$urlRelativeFilePath.'" />';

        ?>
```

Comment: Doesn't [example #3](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/index.php?example=003) not do what you want? And assigning a variable like `$var =  '<img src="'.$urlRelativeFilePath.'" />';`

Comment: Example #1 also covers this.  You should probably read the docs for `QRCode::png()` where it talks about `$pngAbsoluteFilePath` being optional with the default === false.  http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/docs/html/class_q_rcode.html#a1b90c0989105afa06b6e1c718a454fb5

Comment: But there have a problems, is the qr code image sometime is big, sometime is small. Also, the background is black, how can I modify it?